# Passing data from Javascript to php with Laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.1

I need to pass data from Javascript to php using Laravel 5.1
So right now I have a blank page with input(name='q'). When I start typing it sends the query via Ajax data:{q: query} to php so in php I am taking the value from q $query = e(Input::get('q', '')); (Laravel syntaxis) and I am processing the data and I have a respond from the php

```
return response()->json(array(
                    'data' => $data
        ));
```

So after Ajax is succeeded. The ajax is taking the respond :

```
function(item, escape) {
                console.log(item);  }
```

And the output data is object:

```
Object {url: "http://localhost:8000/well/3", name: "Welly", iso3_code: "NOR", class: "product"}
```

So by clicking a button I want to send this data via POST to some method.

After this all I need to take the "item" from js and save it to php variable so via POST I can send this data to differened procces. So after the POST I will have the data for the other process.

I would have access to the object via the respond from the php 'data' => $data 
or from the js "item" .... But whatever I try I can not manage to do it.

Thank for helping me.

EDIT

So at all I have JS object that I need to send as a POST request to the server so after that with php I will do stuffs with the object taken from the JS. Is that clear enough.

Comment: I don't want to be picky, but the English is very poorly written. I'm trying to help you, but I can't understand a good deal of it.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. Just let me know wich part you can not understand

Comment: If what you are asking is how to save that in javascript...show the ajax code

Comment: I need to take the output from the JS which is object and save it in php variable so I can send this with POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do return response via json_encode from php to javascript then in the javascript you can do {{$phpVariable}} = var javascriptVariable